# SQL-Query with joining two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am breaking my brain on a SQL, maybe someone can give me a hint.

Example setup:

```
CREATE TABLE album
(
  name text NOT NULL,
  id serial NOT NULL,
  user_id bigint NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE album_share
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  user_id bigint NOT NULL,
  album_id bigint NOT NULL,
  permission character varying(20)
 );

INSERT INTO album_share VALUES (21, 23, 8, 'OWNER');
--INSERT INTO album_share VALUES (22, 22, 8, 'READ');

INSERT INTO album VALUES ('album1', 8, 23);
INSERT INTO album VALUES ('album2', 12, 23);
INSERT INTO album VALUES ('album3', 13, 22);
INSERT INTO album VALUES ('album4', 15, 22);



--Expecting with user_id=23
-- album1,album2
--!! Failed: album1 is not in the result !!

SELECT * from album a 
LEFT JOIN album_share share ON share.album_id = a.id 
where (a.user_id = 23 or share.user_id = 23)  
  and (share.permission is null or share.permission != 'OWNER');

--Expecting with user_id=22
-- album3,album4
-- Works fine

SELECT * from album a 
LEFT JOIN album_share share ON share.album_id = a.id 
where (a.user_id = 22 or share.user_id = 22)  
  and (share.permission is null or share.permission != 'OWNER');
```

The example is also available online: http://rextester.com/DCD25332

I am trying to select from two tables joined and filterd by their data. It is better explained in the fiddle. The first query with user_id=23 doesn't select the album, I think its because of the filtering, but I can not solve it.

Comment: The reason you are not getting 'album1' in your first query is due to this condition `share.permission is null or share.permission != 'OWNER'`. Since album_id = 8 permission is set to `OWNER`, your SQL criteria will always be FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

The first query does not return a row with `album1` because the associated `album_share.permission` is `OWNER`, which is filtered out as it does not satisfy the condition `permission IS NULL OR permission != 'OWNER'`.

Comment: Yeah right, but i need that condition for the second query with user_id=22

Comment: Try to define which rows you want, first in common English (or other language of your choice), then translate it to SQL. Often the problem goes away when you describe it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

The *album1* has a relation to the *album_share* table and 'share.permission is null' condition never going to be true in that case.

Changing it like below must work,

```
SELECT * from album a 
LEFT JOIN album_share share ON share.album_id = a.id 
where (a.user_id = 23 or share.user_id = 23 or share.permission != 'OWNER');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not because you say you don't want it, look here:

> share.permission != 'OWNER'

This is the same than when the share permision IS NOT 'OWNER'.
if you want the oposite just say '=' and not '!='.

--Expecting with user_id=23
-- album1,album2
--!! Failed: album1 is not in the result !!

SELECT * from album a 
LEFT JOIN album_share share ON share.album_id = a.id where (a.user_id = 23 or share.user_id = 23)  and (share.permission is null or share.permission != 'OWNER');

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the below query you will get 2 records.

```
   SELECT * from album a 
   LEFT JOIN album_share share 
   ON share.album_id = a.id 
   where (a.user_id = 23 or share.user_id = 23);
```

[image: Output]

And then when you add the second condition in `where` clause it filters one record.I don't know if you really want to check if it's permission is not equal to `OWNER`. If you want both the records then you will have to modify the second query and your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT * from album a 
LEFT JOIN album_share share 
ON share.album_id = a.id 
where (a.user_id = 23 or share.user_id = 23)
and (share.permission is null or share.permission = 'OWNER');
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Your Query:

```
SELECT * from album a 
LEFT JOIN album_share share 
ON share.album_id = a.id 
where (a.user_id = 23 or share.user_id = 23)
and (share.permission is null or share.permission != 'OWNER');
```

**Output:**

[image: Output-3]